# pg_dump not dumping the table data

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to download a single table backup which is around `250GB` in size, but when I try to do that using `pg_dump` i do not get data but only get the table structure, may be i am missing something, any help with this would be really great. below is what i am using

```
pg_dump -Upostgres -t "\"table\"" database_name > backup.sql
```

This only dumps the structure but not data. I want the structure as well as data.

Any help in how to achieve this would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Is it a partitioned table? That would explain it, since they contain no data.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, yes this is a partitioned table. how can i back it up in such case?

Comment: You have to tell -t what table partitions are needed as well, not just a single (parent) table

Comment: would it be something like`pg_dump -Upostgres -t "\"table\""  -t "\"table_partition_1\""  -t "\"table_partition_2\"" -t "\"table_partition_3\"" database_name > backup.sql`

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

pg_dump --host ip_address -p port -U user database_name -t table > /tmp/backup.sql